# java tcp ip socket programming regardless of proxy type

Tags: java, sockets

How to write TCP IP socket programming in java. If the client is behind any type of proxy (may be http or socks or no proxy).

Thanks
Bapi

Comment: This is too general to answer.

Comment: Thanks for your information,
Still I need your help. I have created TCP IP socket program that works fine if there is no proxy but it didnot work fine if there is proxy.
So please clarify my problem

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/700161/java-socket-programming-behind-proxy

Answer (score 1):

When I faced such kind of problem I had to code myself http layer (over HTTP CONNECT) and used existing (in standard library) socks layer. However the main problem is to get the proxy settings. As far as I was doing it for a Web Start application, I could use default browser settings.